# Mysql group_concat with in() function

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to use group concat with in function on mysql, it didn't give me any syntax error but i'm not sure its working.

**i'm trying to do something like that:**

```
select
     case
         when weekday(ps.date) in (group_concat(vd.valid_days)) then ps.date
         when weekday(ps.date+1) in (group_concat(vd.valid_days)) then DATE_ADD(ps.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
         when weekday(ps.date+2) in (group_concat(vd.valid_days)) then DATE_ADD(ps.date, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
         when weekday(ps.date+3) in (group_concat(vd.valid_days)) then DATE_ADD(ps.date, INTERVAL 3 DAY)
         when weekday(ps.date+4) in (group_concat(vd.valid_days)) then DATE_ADD(ps.date, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
         when weekday(ps.date+5) in (group_concat(vd.valid_days)) then DATE_ADD(ps.date, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
     end as valid_date
from
    purchase_shopping  ps
    left join
    purchase_region pr on pr.id = ps.idfk_region
    left join
    valid_weeks_days vd on vd.idfk_region = pr.id
group by ps.id
```

what i need basically is to return a valid date if certain day is inside a group concat from a left join. I don't know if my logic is wrong or it does not work.
Obs: The group concat function return something like that: (1,2,5), so it's supposed to work with in() function.

Sample with reworked code data:

```
ps.date = 2018-10-17
weekday(ps.date) = 2 
group_concat(vd.valid_days) = (1,4)
then valid_date will be 2018-10-19
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really hep.

Comment: edited, i've added a sample and reworked the code.

Comment: share sample data and expected output that will really helpful

Comment: I've already added, it's simple as i showed there. The first table will be just one row that can have multiple connections with the third one, which will return the valid days of the week for certain purchase region. So i just want to return the valid purchase day in the final respecting the valid week purchase days.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you simply wants :

```
select (case when uc.id is not null then 'It has items' end)
from shopping_cart sc left join
     user_cart uc
     on uc.id = sc.idfk_cart;
```

Comment: i think that i wasn't very clear, i'm going to rework the code and make a sample data, that won't work in my case, but it would work on that example that i exposed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use result of group_concat in same query so you have to use a subquery

```
select
     case
         when weekday(date) in valid_days then date
         when weekday(date+1) in valid_days then DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
         when weekday(date+2) in valid_days then DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
         when weekday(date+3) in valid_days then DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 3 DAY)
         when weekday(date+4) in valid_days then DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
         when weekday(date+5) in valid_days then DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
     end as valid_date
     from (
     select ps.date, (group_concat(vd.valid_days)) as valid_days
from
    purchase_shopping  ps
    left join
    purchase_region pr on pr.id = ps.idfk_region
    left join
    valid_weeks_days vd on vd.idfk_region = pr.id
group by ps.id
) as sub_query
```

Comment: I've tried that already and it didn't worked, it aways stop on the first value from the group_concat. i don't know why it happens.